# Is there a way to just download a module in the current directory with node / npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm looking for a way to install a module or GitHub repository into the current directory, and not place it in the `node_modules` folder. For example:

```
npm install gituser/hismodule
```

Will install the `hismodule` and the dependencies inside the `node_modules`. But I want to place the Module in the current directory and only place it's dependencies inside `node_modules`.

This could be done by two commands too. One for installating the module and one for installing dependencies. Is there a way to so this?

I didn't find anything so far. Only possible workaround for me is to use `wget` for downloading a `zip` file from GitHub and use `unzip`. But I would like to do this by an known identifier ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do it through npm and I don't think that this is the proper thing to do. The git submodules is more appropriate for something like that. You can define a git repository as a submodule of your repository and every time that you clone the main repository it will clone the submodule as well. They work really well together. You can take a look into this official documentation:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

This article is quite helpful as well:

> The concept of submodules is brilliant. It essentially allows you to
>   attach an external repository inside another repository at a specific
>   path. In order to illustrate the value of submodules, it will probably
>   be helpful for me to explain how I am using them.

https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/

***UPDATE***

You can have something like that instead of giving them a zip file. Create a package.json file and give it to them. In there, add as a dependency your root and define the postinstall script as well. Something like that:

```
{
  "name": "your-dummy-packagejson",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "mv node_modules/your-project ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "your-project-dependency": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

- They save this package.json in their pc
- They run npm install
- After the installation the postinstall hook will run and it will execute the `mv node_modules/your-project .` command.
- Your project is ready :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think a submodule is not the right thing for this. I'll try to explain what I want: The Module is the `root` for other projects. Think more about it as a framework. But I want a simple way/command for developers to install it out of github. Yes, then could download, extract and delete an zip archive, but I would like to have just `npm` or `node` do the job ...

Comment: @eisbehr 'I want a simple way/command for developers to install it out of github', does this mean that you don't want the devs to clone the repository from github?

Comment: No, I'm saying that not all devs are familiar with `git` too. ;) But so far it would be the best idea to do so ...

Comment: @eisbehr your life will be easier if you try to train them a bit :)

Comment: Because it's an open source project I don't have the resources for this. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr Just updated the answer. I think that something like that will simplify the process of installing the project. You just need to give them a package.json file and tell them to run npm install instead of npm install your-project

Comment: I had an similar Idea like you. But this has more impacts as I thought. Like `mv` will not copy `dot` files. You could fix that with using `shopt -s dotglob` in your command. But another thing is that the `package.json` of the moule will be changed trough `npm install`, whats not so nice for further usage. But I'm glad someone else had the same ideas as I.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the prefix option:

```
npm install --prefix <path/to/prefix_folder> -g
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But `--prefix` only moves the `node_modules` in another folder. It has the same result as a normal install, just in another sub-directory.